# After press a key, view go down, only in S3

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a weird problem. I have a view with a editext field, when the user tap over this, the keyboard shows (I'm using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"), so this is ok. The problem happen when I press any key, after that, the view goes down and the keyboard keep visible, so the edittext is hidden behind the keyboard. I don't know why is happening that. My code is working on S2, Nexus 4 and HTC One, and only is failing in Samsung Galaxy S3. If I change the windowSoftInputMode to adjustResize, it's works, but I don't want that. I also check with the OnFocusChangeListener, but the focus in the edittext doesn't change when I press a key. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code please? Also, what versions of Android the phones are running? It could be an OS issue and not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem still occur if you use a different keyboard app?  If the problem is limited to only the Samsung keyboard, it may be the keyboard that is at fault, in which case there is probably little you can do about it.

Comment: It's the keyboard that is at fault. But my Galaxy S3 still want to use my app. And the Galaxy s3 is a best seller.

Comment: Even among S3 users, how many are using the Samsung keyboard?  I own an S3 myself and the current firmware bundles Swype and uses it by default instead of the Samsung keyboard.